# Adding column and index to dataframe makes values NaN

Tags: python, r, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

How can I change the `index` and `column` so that my values stay the same as in the first table? I don't understand why adding some indices changes my values to NaN.

This is what I have:

```
Tabelle = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(pfad, header = 2))
print Tabelle[:2]
                          0              1      81  60  5  63  73
0  2014-03-19T12:44:32.695Z  1395233072695  703425   0  2   1  13   
1  2014-03-19T12:44:32.727Z  1395233072727  703425   0  2   1  13
```

That's what I want:
(Problem: loggerFile is no dataFrame, see at end of question)

```
Tabelle = pd.DataFrame(loggerFile, columns = ID_columns, index = RowIndex)
print Tabelle[:2]

ID --->                               0              1      81 60  5 63  73  
Zeilen-Index                                                                  
1395233072695  2014-03-19T12:44:32.695Z  1395233072695  703425  0  2  1  13   
1395233072727  2014-03-19T12:44:32.727Z  1395233072727  703425  0  2  1  13
```

That's what I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------    
Tabelle = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(pfad), index = RowIndex)
print Tabelle[:2]

              Time Unixtime  Typ   grunz quak  bla blab Blub  \
Zeilen-Index                                                                
1395233072695  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  NaN   
1395233072727  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  NaN
----------------------------------------------------------------    
Tabelle = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(pfad), columns = ID_columns, index = RowIndex)
print Tabelle[:2]

ID --->         0   1  81  60   5  63  73  
Zeilen-Index                                                                 
1395233072695 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN    
1395233072727 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   

----------------------------------------------------------------
Tabelle = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(pfad), columns = ID_columns)
print Tabelle[:2]

ID --->   0   1  81  60   5  63  73  
0       NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
1       NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

But if I make a list like:

```
loggerFile =

[['2014-03-19T12:44:32.695Z', '1395233072695', '703425', '0', '2', '1', '13', '5', '21', '25', '0', '25', '209', '0', '145', '0', '0'], ['2014-03-19T12:44:32.727Z', '1395233072727', '703425', '0', '2', '1', '13', '5', '21', '25', '0', '25', '209', '0', '146', '0', '0'], ['2014-03-19T12:44:32.758Z', '1395233072758', '703425', '0', '2', '1', '13', '5', '21', '25', '0', '25', '209', '0', '145', '0', '0'], ['2014-03-19T12:44:32.790Z', '1395233072790', '703425', '0', '2', '1', '13', '5', '21', '25', '0', '25', '209', '0', '145', '0', '0'], ['2014-03-19T12:44:32.821Z', '1395233072821', '703425', '0', '2', '1', '13', '5', '21', '25', '0', '25', '209', '0', '145', '0', '0']]
```

And add it as data, it works:

```
Tabelle = pd.DataFrame(loggerFile, columns = ID_columns, index = RowIndex)

ID --->                               0              1      81 60  5 63  73  
Zeilen-Index                                                                  
1395233072695  2014-03-19T12:44:32.695Z  1395233072695  703425  0  2  1  13   
1395233072727  2014-03-19T12:44:32.727Z  1395233072727  703425  0  2  1  13
```

My `ID_columns` is made this way out of a list:

```
ID_columns = pd.Index(ID_list, name="ID --->")
```

Where the list `ID_list` looks like

```
['0', '1', '81', '60', '5', '63', '73', nan, '10', '11', '2', '16', '30', '20', '33', '94', '61']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not reading the csv file properly, try:

```
 pd.read_csv(pfad,sep='\s+')
```